# Como contar diferentes datos de un atributo en el controlador de laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buen día, tengo un problema con una consulta:

El problema es que tengo una tabla que se llama quejas, en estas tengo un atributo que se llama status_queja donde tengo los Siguentes elementos SOLVENTADO, PENDIENTE, ACTIVO, CANCELADO y quiero contar la cantidad de registro que hay con cada uno de esos 4 status, intente realizar mi consulta de la siguente forma

```
$QuejaSub =DB::table('quejas')
    ->select(DB::raw(COUNT(T_IF('quejas.status_queja', '=', 'PENDIENTE', '1', 'NULL')) 'PENDIENTE',
        COUNT(T_IF('quejas.status_queja', '=','ACTIVO', '1', 'NULL')) 'ACTIVO',
        COUNT(T_IF('quejas.status_queja', '=','CANCELADO', '1', 'NULL')) 'CANCELADO',
        COUNT(T_IF('quejas.status_queja', '=','SOLVENTADO', '1', 'NULL')) 'SOLVENTADO'))
        ->FROM('quejas','reportes')
        -> WHERE ('quejas.id_reporte', '=', 'reportes.id_reporte', 'AND' , '=', 'SUBDIRECCION ACADEMICA');
```

Pero me arroja el siguente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la consulta que trato de hacer pero con laravel 6
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si, los modelos están creados y puedo acceder a las tablas pero no se como representar esto
SELECT 
 COUNT(IF(quejas.status_queja = 'PENDIENTE', 1, NULL)) 'PENDIENTE',
 COUNT(IF(quejas.status_queja = 'ACTIVO', 1, NULL)) 'ACTIVO',
    COUNT(IF(quejas.status_queja = 'CANCELADO', 1, NULL)) 'CANCELADO',
    COUNT(IF(quejas.status_queja = 'SOLVENTADO', 1, NULL)) 'SOLVENTADO'
FROM quejas,reportes

WHERE quejas.id_reporte =reportes.id_reporte AND reportes.subdireccion='SUBDIRECCION ACADEMICA';

En la estructura de laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que la aproximación para dar solución se puede mejorar considerando lo siguiente:

- Usa al modelo
- Usa un `CASE WHEN` en conjunto con `COUNT` para generar las columnas de forma condicionada con base en el `status_queja`
- Usa el método `selectRaw()` para pasar sentencias SQL, teniendo múltiples sentencias SQL dentro de un mismo método brindando capacidad de leer sentencias SQL puras y de forma mas organizada
- Usa un *join explícito* para vincular ambas tablas en lugar de la sintaxis antigua que empleas
- En un `where` por separado vas a evaluar la condición de la subdirección

Podemos entonces hacerlo aasí:

```
$consulta = Queja::selectRaw("
                        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_queja = 'PENDIENTE' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Pendiente,
                        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_queja = 'ACTIVO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Activo,
                        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_queja = 'CANCELADO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Cancelado,
                        COUNT(CASE WHEN status_queja = 'SOLVENTADO' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Solventado
            ")->join('reportes', 'quejas.id_reporte', '=', 'reportes.id_reporte')
                ->where('reportes.subdireccion', 'SUBDIRECCION ACADEMICA')
                ->get();
```

Te sugiero leas a detalle los siguientes recursos:

- [métodos `raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)
- [sentencia `CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)
- [`joins` en SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: si arroja el resultado que esperaba .

Muchisimas Gracias